# Checklist of things to do to improve couchdb single document operation performance

Tags: nosql, couchdb

There are some very simple things that we all can do to get better couchdb performance. I'm interested in aggregating a simple list. For example, I've heard that having sequential id's boost performance incredibly. What other things can we do? What are the *most* important things that everyone can do, what are your experiences, and what has helped *you* most?

Comment: Just a tip for folks new to Couch that thought seq IDs are the key to good health (like I did) they can get you into some nasty collision situations when you have master-master replication setup. So UUIDs will be slower, but keep you out of these potential problematic edge cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177481/performance-of-long-ids/2196805#2196805

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `Definitive Guide`: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html

Some other points:

- sequential UUIDs instead of totally random
- don't use `include_docs=true` but emit full docs (view size <=> speed trade-off)
- prefer batch and bulk operations

Comment: Great tips, just adding a footnote for new folks that if you emit your complete docs instead of using include_docs=true, keep in mind this is effectively *doubling* your data set from your DB into your index. In non-huge data sets this will improve retrieval time, but in HUGE data sets, it will double your disk space requirements. Just keep that in mind.