# CouchDB - human readable id

Tags: node.js, couchdb

Im using CouchDB with node.js. Right now there is one node involved and even in remote future its not planned to changed that. While I can remove most of the cases where a short and auto-incremental-like (it can be sparse but not like random) ID is required there remains one place where the users actually needs to enter the ID of a product. I'd like to keep this ID as short as possible and in a more human readable format than something like '4ab234acde242349b' as it sometimes has to be typed by hand and so on.

However in the database it can be stored with whatever ID pleases CouchDB (using the default auto generated UUID) but it should be possible to give it a number that can be used to identify it as well. What I have thought about is creating a document that consists of an array with all the UUIDs from CouchDB. When in node I create a new product I would run an update handler that updates said document with the new unique ID at the end. To obtain the products ID I'd then query the array and client side using indexOf I could get the index as a short ID.

I dont know if this is feasible. From the performance point of view I can say the following: There are more queries that should do numerical ID -> uuid than uuid -> numerical ID. There will be at max 7000 new entries a year in the database. Also there is no use case where a product can be deleted yet I'd like not to rely on that.

Are there any other applicable ways to genereate a shorter and more human readable ID that can be associated with my document?

**/EDIT**
From a technical point of view: It seems to be working. I can do both conversions number <-> uuid and it seems go well. I dont now if this works well with replication and stuff but as there is said array i guess it should, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here:

1. Set your human readable id as `_id` field. Basically you can just set in create document calls to DB, and it will accept it. This can be a more lightweight solution, but it comes with some limitations:

   1. It has to be unique. You should also be careful about clients trying to create documents, but instead overwrite existing ones.
   2. It can only contain alphanumeric or a few special characters. In my experience it is asking for trouble to have extra character types.
   3. It cannot be longer than a theoretical string length limit(Couchdb doesn't define any, but you should). [Long ids will increase your views(indexes) size really bad](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#A_id). [And it might make it s lower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177481/774086).

   If these things are no problem with you, then you should go with this solution.
2. As you said yourself, let the `_id` be a UUID, and set the human readable id to another field. To reach the document by  the human readable id, you can just create a [view](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) emitting the human readable id as a key, and then either emit the document as value or get the document via [`include_docs=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) option. Whenever the view is reached Couchdb will update the view incrementally and return you the list. This is really same as you creating a document with an array/object of ids inside it. Except with using a couchdb view, you get more performance.

   This might be also slightly slower on querying and inserting. If the ids are inserted sequentially, it's fine, if not, [CouchDB will slightly take more time to insert it at the right place](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#A_id). These don't work well with huge amounts of insert coming at the DB.

   Querying shouldn't be more than 10% of total query time longer than first option. I think 10% is really a big number. It will be most probably less than 5%, I remember in my CouchDB application, I switched from reading by _id to reading from a view by a key and the slow down was very little that from user end point, when making 100 queries at the same time, it wasn't noticeable.

   This is how people, query documents by other fields than id, for example querying a user document with email, when the user is logging in.

If you don't know how couchdb views work, you should read the [views chapter](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/views.html) of [couchdb definite guide book](http://guide.couchdb.org/index.html).

Also make sure you stay away from documents with huge arrays inside them. I think CouchDB, has a limit of 4GB per document. I remember having many documents and it had really long querying times because the view had to iterate on each array item. In the end for each array item, instead I created one document. It was way faster.